# Descargar archivos mayor a 10MB con java ee 7 y tomcat

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una app web con java EE 7 en un servidor apache tomcat 8.0.5, el problema es que al momento de descargar un archivo desde la interfaz para hacerlo, no lo hace, descarga el archivo pero al momento de ir por los 10MB, se corta la descarga, no sé porqué, espero me puedan ayudar con alguna configuración en el servidor Tomcat o en el web.xml del java ee 7.

Las configuraciones las estoy realizando en un appconfig en java no en xml.

Para la descarga tengo un Bean con una variable de StreamedContent en donde lo cargo con una variable de tipo File.

En la vista, con Primefaces  un commandButton y dentro de él un fileDownload que hace referencia a la variable del StreamedContent

Comment: podrías añadir el web.config, igual es por que está limitada la descarga

Comment: en el web.xml no tengo ninguna configuración para limitar la descarga y si es de configurar ahí, como sería la configuración?